# Using a SSR for passing a DC PWM Signal that has positive and negative waveform

Tags: dc, pwm, solid-state-relay, solenoid, waveform

I am trying to control the PWM signal to a solenoid via an SSR by passing one leg through it to control the on/off.

I have tried 3 different SSR's and none of them fully stop the signal, I still get a partial signal through (Still haven't hooked an O-Scope up yet sorry!)

This occurs regardless of whether the SSR is energized or not.

The waveform looks like this. 0V->+48V ->+24V-> -48V ->0v

I thought I needed an SSR that had an AC inductance rating but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be great!

Comment: SSRs are not all the same. They are internally multiple components and therefore can behave differently. "*I still get a partial signal*" What does this actually mean?

Comment: Some AC SSRs use triacs, some use FETs. What type have you got?

Comment: A SSR, particularly one using a TRIAC or SCRs, will usually have a snubber, which will conduct some AC current, but typically maybe 10-20 mA or so. That may show up as some voltage on an inductive load, but should not be so much as to activate the solenoid. Please provide a schematic - I don't know what you mean by "passing one leg through it".

Comment: I just noticed that you are trying to control a bipolar PWM signal, which is likely much higher than mains power frequency, and it will have high frequency components in the transitions, so that will pass much more of the signal to the load. Please provide details of your PWM signal.

Answer (score 0):

ON-OFF control can be implemented with MOSFETs. The general idea with a bipolar MOSFET switch is to connect two devices of the same type - here it's NMOS - back-to-back.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM337b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The PWM and ON/OFF voltage waveforms in this example are as follows:

[image: PWM and ON/OFF control voltage waveforms]

The solenoid coil current looks as below:

[image: Solenoid coil current waveform]

The gate voltage has to be floating relative to the common node between the MOSFETs. We can implement that by using a bit of power from the PWM pin.

In the circuit below, there's a floating 12V power supply rail, FL_12V, referenced to the common source node of the output-controlling mosfets M1 and M2.

A 5V logic signal ON_OFF is used to switch the power to the solenoid. It is opto-isolated and regenerated by Q2 as a gate drive voltage.

D3-Q3 form an undervoltage lockout circuit that prevents the MOSFETs from turning on unless there's enough supply voltage to ensure they stay saturated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6D8M.png)</sup>

The PWM, ON/OFF and floating power supply input voltage are plotted below.

[image: The PWM, ON/OFF and floating power supply input voltage waveforms]

The solenoid current waveform is shown below.

[image: Solenoid current waveform]

It would be also nice to only switch the solenoid on/off between the PWM cycles.

This can be implemented on the floating (isolated) side of the circuit: when the PWM is at 0V, the ON/OFF signal is sampled into C4. When the PWM signal goes away from 0V, the current state of the ON/OFF signal is thus latched and keeps the solenoid either ON or OFF until the following PWM cycle.

To keep the schematic readable, the floating voltage supply and the ON/OFF optocoupler have been replaced by their equivalent elements V3 and I1, respectively. They would be unchanged from the previous circuit.

The circuit in the left half of the schematic detects non-zero PWM voltage and activates the 2nd optocoupler. This optocoupler then generates the HOLD signal on the floating side, and controls the pass gate M10-M11, acting as a sampling switch for the storage capacitor C4.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQQIn.png)</sup>

The solenoid current is only switched on/off when the PWM signal is idle. The solenoid current and the on/off optotransistor current are plotted below.

[image: Solenoid and magnified on/off optotransistor current waveform in the circuit with sample-and-hold]